# Minor ticks not drawing with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Why the lines are not drawn at x = -4.5 and y = -3.5 when they are drawn at x=10.5 and y=4.5 ?

How to align the text "0" to the baseline of the labels of the x-axis ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\usetikzlibrary[arrows.meta,bending]
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,shapes}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
 restrict x to domain=-5:11, xmax=11, xmin=-5,
 restrict y to domain=-4:5, ymax=5, ymin=-4,
 x=1cm,
 y=1cm,
 axis x line = middle,
 axis y line = middle,
 axis line style =ultra thick,
 major tick style=black,
 grid=both,
 major grid style=lightgray,
 minor grid style=lightgray,
 minor tick num=1,
 xtick={-4,...,10},
 ytick={-3,...,4},
 extra x ticks={-5,11},
 extra y ticks={-4,5},
 extra y tick label={\null},
 extra x tick label={\null},
 extra tick style={tick style={draw=none}},
 samples=1000,
 >=stealth,
  ]

\addplot[thick,smooth,domain=-4:10] {3.5*(x-2)*(x+1)/(x^2-3*x+4)}; 

\node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.4] at (-4,1.96975){};

\node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.4] at (10,4.16216){};

\node[below left] at (axis cs:0,0) {$0$};

\node[below] at (axis cs:10.8,-0.1) {$x$};

\node[left] at (axis cs:-0.1,4.8) {$y$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Version 1

You ask

> Why the lines are not drawn at x = -4.5 and y = -3.5 ?

and in your code you have

```
 xtick={-4,...,10},
 ytick={-3,...,4},
 extra x ticks={-5,11},
 extra y ticks={-4,5},
```

Is your question serious? Because you request in your code to have *extra* ticks at

**x = -5 and 11** and **y = -4 and 5**

and *normal* ticks at **x = -4 to 10 in steps of 1** and **y = -3 to 4 in steps of 1**.

And because of the shifted zero/0 (`\node[below left] at (axis cs:0,0) {$0$};`) on the origin, have a look at `ticklabel cs` in the manual.

### Version 2

Here's the solution to your tick problem - I don't know how to easily add the zero and I think it is not necessary in your case.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 xmax=11, 
 xmin=-5,
 ymax=5, 
 ymin=-4,
 axis x line = middle,
 axis y line = middle,
 grid=both,
 major grid style=lightgray,
 minor grid style=red,
 % Visualize extra tick grid
 extra tick style={
   major grid style=blue,
   },
 minor tick num=1,
 xtick={-2,0,...,10},
 ytick={-3,...,4},
 extra x ticks={-4.5},
 extra y ticks={-3.5},
  ]
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I really don't get what you did there :). Maybe you did too many steps at once in your code.

I changed the color of the grid to indicate **major grid**, **minor grid** and **extra grid**.

Comment: @Manuel Your answer is useful but does not solve my problem. Add `extra x ticks={-5,-4.5,11},
 extra y ticks={-4,-3.5,5},`is an interim solution.